# PHP/MySQL select query issues

Tags: php, mysql, database

I was wondering if anyone could give me a hand. I currently have 3 tables as follows:

users(user_id, username, first_name, last_name, password)
module(module_id, name, crn)
userModule(user_id, module_id)

What would be the best way to access this? From doing basic research it looks like a RIGHT JOIN would be appropriate...

How would I go about looking at the modules table based on the user_id variable?

I gave it ago here but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM module JOIN userModule ON (module.module_id = userModule.module_id) JOIN users ON (userModule.user_id = users.user_id) WHERE user_id = 2");

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];
```

Comment: sorry that was just me copy/pasting errors. its fixed now

Comment: if you add error checking it should tell you what your errors are. is it module or modules, it's inconsistent between your question and your query.

Comment: When I try to run my code it gives the following error: Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\fyp3\index.php on line 13.

I'll edit the code into the original post.

Comment: please add or die(mysql_error()); after your mysql_query, like this:

mysql_query("...") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Sorry I'm abit of a PHP noob. I assume this is for debugging to give better debugging errors because in my code we don't even know if the query worked in the first place?

Comment: Yes it is. mysql_fetch_row clearly failed because the query was wrong in the first place. So adding or die(mysql_error()); would, well, print an error if the query fails. It will usually tell you what is wrong in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM modules LEFT JOIN userModule ON userModule.module_id = modules.module_id WHERE userModule.user_id = 2");
```

It should work!

Better yet, if you only want to get modules info:

```
SELECT modules.* FROM modules ....
```

I used LEFT JOIN but there are several other methods : RIGHT JOIN, INNER JOIN or FULL JOIN. See what's the difference between those methods here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Also, you should always add " or die(mysql_error());" after your mysql_query(). If the query is wrong (bad formatting, miswritten fields, etc.) it will print a useful error.

Comment: I want the modules for specific users that get logged in. Your query worked for me beautifully. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. You just forgot to specify a JOIN method. It's always either LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, INNER JOIN or FULL JOIN but never just "JOIN". At least I think.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, JOIN is the same as INNER JOIN. So the error was probably elsewhere. Anyway, cheers!

Comment: Except.... never use `or die(mysql_error());` in real code.  You shouldn't be displaying raw errors to your users.

Comment: Of course it's a debugging tool. Even if one could argue that at the point you're actually having users, you shouldn't expect errors. :o)